# Not possible to connect some countries

Tags: guard-node, node, entry

I was running Tor-0.2.9.9 till yestoday, thene I updated to the new version Tor-0.4.5.5-rc now i cannot connect to Japan or India anymore and also to some other countries. In version Tor-0.2.9.9 it still works.

WHY?

**torrc**

```
StrictNodes 1
EntryNodes {in} 
ExitNodes {in}
ExcludeNodes {fr},{de},{nl},{gb},{us}
ExcludeExitNodes {fr},{de},{nl},{gb},{us}
GeoIPExcludeUnknown 1
```

---

**Update**

**Living in a bubble**
In Tor, it has been possible for a long time to configure the `Exit/Entry-Nodes` according to your wishes. In the new Tor versions, if you enter certain country codes for the `Exit/Entry-Node` in the config, Tor cannot connect.

**Why is that?**

I use the old Tor version and I can connect to any country in the world. The majority of Internet users live in a small part of the Internet like in their own world, a bubble.

**Same Config - New Tor Version 0.4.5.8**

> [notice] Tor 0.4.5.8 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.11-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1f, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4, Libzstd 1.4.4 and Glibc 2.31 as libc.
> [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
> [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc".
> [warn] You have asked to exclude certain relays from all positions in your circuits. Expect hidden services and other Tor features to be broken
> in unpredictable ways.
> [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
> [notice] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9050
> [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
> [notice] Opened Control listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9051
> [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/local/share/tor/geoip.
> [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/local/share/tor/geoip6.
> [notice] Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
> [warn] Your configuration excludes 100% of all possible guards. That's likely to make you stand out from the rest of the world.
> [notice] Starting with guard context "restricted"
> [warn] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path.
> Discarding this circuit.
> [notice] Our circuit 0 (id: 1) died due to an invalid selected path, purpose General-purpose client. This may be a torrc configuration issue, or a bug.
> [warn] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
> [warn] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
> [warn] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.

**Same Config - Old Tor Version 0.2.9.9**

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look like valid syntax to me. Try again without the `StrictNodes 1` text and post your Tor log.

Comment: I have no log file.

Comment: You can log to a file by including the [`Log` line](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#Log2) in your torrc file.

Comment: I added "Log /var/log/tor.log" to the torrc an get: [warn] Couldn't parse log levels in Log option 'Log /var/log/tor.log'- [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to validate Log options. See logs for details. - [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.

Comment: You need to include the log level, so try for example `Log info /var/log/tor.log`.

Comment: `[warn] Couldn't parse log levels in Log option 'Log info /var/log/tor.log'`

Comment: Oops, should be `Log info file /var/log/tor.log` as on the webpage I linked to.

Comment: `[warn] Couldn't open file for 'Log info file /var/log/tor.log': Permission denied`   - I have to tell you that I compiled Tor myself and gave it a user and group.
These are not default settings.